# why is this use of % in a Linux shell script not working?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm using % to determine while numbers are divisible by 5.  But it appears to always return '0' indicating everything is evenly divisible by 5.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh

n=20
i=1
# loop while i <= n
while [ $i -lt $n ] || [ $i -eq $n ]
do

# find the numbers that are evenly divisible by '5'

  m=`expr $n % 5`
  if [ $m -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $i" is evenly divisible by 5"
  fi

  # do i = i + 1
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

My output looks like this:

```
1 is evenly divisible by 5
2 is evenly divisible by 5
3 is evenly divisible by 5
4 is evenly divisible by 5
5 is evenly divisible by 5
6 is evenly divisible by 5
7 is evenly divisible by 5
8 is evenly divisible by 5
9 is evenly divisible by 5
10 is evenly divisible by 5
11 is evenly divisible by 5
12 is evenly divisible by 5
13 is evenly divisible by 5
14 is evenly divisible by 5
15 is evenly divisible by 5
16 is evenly divisible by 5
17 is evenly divisible by 5
18 is evenly divisible by 5
19 is evenly divisible by 5
20 is evenly divisible by 5
```

Comment: Your logic is all good, you just used the wrong variable.  `$i` is your operand, not `$n`.  Just change to `m=\`expr $i % 5\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n is always 20 so "m=`expr $n % 5" will always be 0